# Calling methods within methods to Titleize in Ruby

Tags: ruby, capitalize

I am trying to create a titleizing method for a programming assignment, it capitalizes certain words and ignores others. It always capitalizes the first word. To this end, I made a method that finds the first word of a string, and tried to call it within the titleize method. I'm getting an error that says "warning: string literal in condition". I've tried changing the phrasing of the if loop around, but it's not fixing my error. Can anyone explain to my why my code is broken? Thanks so much for your help!

```
def first_word(str)
    array = str.split(' ')
    return array[0]
end

def titleize(str)
    words = str.split
    words.each do |word| 
        if word != first_word(str)
            word.capitalize!
        elsif word != 'and' or 'the'
            word.capitalize!
        end
        words.join ' '
    end
end
```

Comment: By the way: your code is inefficient. Consider a very long string with many word -- splitting it consumes time and memory. In every cycle of your `words.each` loop you call `first_word()`, which again splits the whole string. It would be better to do `first_word = words.first`, and use the `first_word` variable in your loop.

Comment: Your code incorrectly capitalizes a non-initial word that is identical to the initial word.

Comment: @sawa you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Change the following

```
elsif word != 'and' or 'the'
```

to

```
elsif word != 'and' or word != 'the'
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator `!=` has higher precedence than `or`. It means that this line

```
elsif word != 'and' or 'the'
```

is equivalent to

```
elsif (word != 'and') or 'the'
```

and not to

```
elsif word != ('and' or 'the')
```

as you probably expected. The latter equivalence should be expressed as

```
elsif word != 'and' or word != 'the'
```

but even in this case it would not make a lot of sense and it's very hard to read.

You may want to change the link to

```
elsif !%w(and the).include?(word)
```

Comment: +1 for "it would not make a lot of sense and it's very hard to read". The readability for that conditional construct is very bad. Part of it is "`'and' or`", which is legal, but it *looks* like a syntax error at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'abc'
p "hi" if str == '1' or '12'
#=> warning: string literal in condition
```

or

```
str = 'abc'
p "hi" if (str == '1' or '12')
#=> warning: string literal in condition
p "hi" if '12'
#=> warning: string literal in condition
```

This happened as ruby interpreter sees  your code as below:

```
p "hi" if str == '1' or true
```

The second one will always evaluates to true, because `'12'` always exist. The warning is saying that instead of a `boolean` or `test`, you have a string literal, `'12'`, which always evaluates to *`true`*.

So a fix is as below:

```
p "hi" if str == '1' or str == '12' #=> "hi"
p "hi" if ['1','12'].include? str #=> "hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how readable this is. But it's short!

```
def titleize(str)
  str.capitalize.split.map do |word|
    %w{and the}.include?(word.downcase) ? word : word.capitalize
  end.join(' ')
end
```