# If/Else as a {Code Block}?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, boolean

So I'm trying to define "#titleize," a method that will capitalize the first letters of all words in a string, *except fluff words such as 'the,' 'and,' and 'if.'*

My code so far:

```
def titleize(string)
words = []
stopwords = %w{the a by on for of are with just but and to the my had some in} 

string.scan(/\w+/) do |word|
    if !stopwords.include?(word) 
        words << word.capitalize
    else 
        words << word 
    end

words.join(' ')
end
```

My trouble is with the if/else section - I'm getting "syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end" when I run the method on a string.

I think the code would work if I used the shorthand version of if/else, which normally goes into code blocks inside of {curly brackets}. I know that the syntax for this shorthand looks like something along the lines of

```
string.scan(/\w+/) { |word| !stopwords.include?(word) words << word.capitalize : words       
    <<  word }
```

...with

```
words << word.capitalize
```

occurring if !stopwords.include?(word) returns true, and

```
words << word
```

occurring if !stopwords.include?(word) returns false. But this isn't working either!

It may also look something like this (which is a bit of a different/more efficient approach - no separate array instantiated):

```
string.scan(/\w+/) do |word|
    !stopwords.include?(word) word.capitalize : word
end.join(' ')
```

(From [Calling methods within methods to Titleize in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129479/calling-methods-within-methods-to-titleize-in-ruby))
...but I'm receiving "syntax error" messages when I run this code as well.

So! Does anyone know the syntax I'm referring to? Could you help me remember it?
Or, can you point out another reason that this bit of code isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missin an `end`:

```
string.scan(/\w+/) do |word|
    if !stopwords.include?(word) 
        words << word.capitalize
    else 
        words << word 
    end
end #<<<<add this
```

For the shorthand version do this:

```
string.scan(/\w+/).map{|w| stopwords.include?(w) ? w : w.capitalize}.join(' ')
```

Comment: You are right, she is missing `end` in the first code sample (`if .. then` statement), and she forgot `?` in the ternary operator `.. ? .. : ..` in the second sample.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. As for the missing end, what a silly oversight on my part - I guess I should expect that after coding for four hours. As for the "shorthand" - that also works, thank you - is this syntax always known as the "ternary operator?"

Comment: PS - Boris, I'm male.

Comment: @user2839246 the `condition ? ... : ...` is know as the ternary operator...might be called something else too so not sure about always.

Answer (score 1):

Active Support has the `titleize` method, which is useful as a starting point, because it'll capitalize the words in a string, however it's not entirely intelligent; It lays waste to stopwords. A touch of post-processing to restore them fixes this up nicely though.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'

STOPWORDS = Hash[
  %w{the a by on for of are with just but and to the my had some in}.map{ |w| 
    [w.capitalize, w]
  }
]


def my_titlize(str)
  str.titleize.gsub(
    /(?!^)\b(?:#{ STOPWORDS.keys.join('|') })\b/,
    STOPWORDS
  )
end
# => /(?!^)\b(?:The|A|By|On|For|Of|Are|With|Just|But|And|To|My|Had|Some|In)\b/

my_titlize('Jackdaws love my giant sphinx of quartz.')
# => "Jackdaws Love my Giant Sphinx of Quartz."

my_titlize('the rain in spain stays mainly in the plain.')
# => "The Rain in Spain Stays Mainly in the Plain."

my_titlize('Negative lookahead is indispensable')
# => "Negative Lookahead Is Indispensable"
```

The reason I do this is it's really easy to build a YAML file, or a database table, to provide the list of stopwords. From that array of words it's easy to build a hash, and a regex, which is fed to `gsub`, which then uses the regex engine to touch-up the stopwords.

The hash created is:

```
{
  "The"=>"the",
  "A"=>"a",
  "By"=>"by",
  "On"=>"on",
  "For"=>"for",
  "Of"=>"of",
  "Are"=>"are",
  "With"=>"with",
  "Just"=>"just",
  "But"=>"but",
  "And"=>"and",
  "To"=>"to",
  "My"=>"my",
  "Had"=>"had",
  "Some"=>"some",
  "In"=>"in"
}
```

The regex created is:

```
/(?!^)\b(?:The|A|By|On|For|Of|Are|With|Just|But|And|To|My|Had|Some|In)\b/
```

When `gsub` gets a hit on a word in the regex pattern, it does a lookup in the hash and substitutes the value back into the string.

The code could use `downcase` or other calculated ways of reversing the upper-cased words, but that adds overhead. `gsub`, and the regex engine, are very fast. Part of that is because the hash and the regex avoid looping over the stopword list, so that list can be huge without it slowing the code much. Of course, the engine has changed over the different versions of Ruby, so older versions don't do as well, so run benchmarks for Ruby < 2.0.

Comment: Hmm... This is interesting. But a bit over my head, because I'm a programming newb. I'll have to look back at this when I've gained a bit more proficiency. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to hunt bugs in suboptimal code. Do it in a canonical way, and make possible errors easy to spot.

```
class String
  SQUELCH_WORDS = %w{the a by on for of are with just but and to the my had some in}

  def titleize
    gsub /\w+/ do |s|
      SQUELCH_WORDS.include?( s ) ? s : s.capitalize
    end
  end
end

"20,000 miles under the sea".titleize #=> "20,000 Miles Under the Sea"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only are you missing an `end` (to close the method), your `words.join(' ')` is inside the `scan` block, which means `words is joining every time you iterate through`scan`.

I think you want this:

```
def titleize(string)
  words = []
  stopwords = %w{the a by on for of are with just but and to the my had some in} 

  string.scan(/\w+/) do |word|
      if !stopwords.include?(word) 
          words << word.capitalize
      else 
          words << word 
      end
  end

  words.join(' ')
end
```

while your code could be cleaned up, the basic flow is sound at this point.